# My variable, when created in an if statement only exist when the if statement is true

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I am creating a code for a game and when your mouse is over an enemy and the enemy is clicked on, your character chases after the enemy. So, I created the enemy as a variable because I don't want the character to chase after the enemy if what is clicked on is just an arbitrary object. The code then checks to see if the property 'enemy' is inside of the object clicked on and if it is then the object chases after that object.

```
if click.positive:
    obj = mouse.hitObject
    if 'enemy' in obj:
        own['attack'] = 1
    else:
        own['attack'] = 0
```

when own['attack'] = 1, the player chases after the enemy however the compiler says that obj does not exist. It does however exist when the mouse is initially clicked but not afterwards. I understand that the variable only exists when the mouse is clicked because if the mouse isn't clicked then its not ever going to get around to assigning the variable. But how else could I right it so if the enemy is clicked on once, the player will continue to chase the enemy until something else is clicked?

this is the error I got

```
NameError: global name 'obj' is not defined
```

This is the entire code if you feel like reading through it all also it was coded in blender as evident with "import bge":

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

flagEmpty = scene.objects['Flag Empty']
flag = scene.objects['Flag']
enemy = scene.objects['Enemy Physics Box']

mouse = cont.sensors[1]
click = cont.sensors[0]

track = cont.actuators[0]
message = cont.actuators[1]
blur = cont.actuators[2]

hit = mouse.hitPosition
distance = own.getDistanceTo(flagEmpty)
enemyDistance = own.getDistanceTo(enemy)

if 'init' not in own:
    own['init'] = True
    own['fric'] = .85
    own['maxspd'] = 5
    own['speed'] = 0.0
    own['accel'] = .2
    own['attack'] = obj

def main():
    if click.positive:
        global obj
        obj = mouse.hitObject
        if 'enemy' in obj:
            own['attack'] = obj
        if 'enemy' not in obj:
            own['attack'] = obj
    if own['attack'] == obj:
         attack()
    if own['attack'] == None:
         free()
def free():
    if own['attack'] == None:
        cont.deactivate(blur)
    if click.positive:
        if hit.z < -.34:
            if hit.z > -.36:
                flagEmpty.position = hit

    if distance > 1:
        own['speed'] += own['accel']
        cont.activate(message)
        cont.activate(track)
        flag.visible = True
    else:
        own['speed'] *= own['fric']
        cont.deactivate(track)
        cont.deactivate(message)
        flag.visible = False
    speed()
def attack():
    enemyDist = own.getDistanceTo(obj)
    if own['attack'] == obj:
        cont.activate(blur)
        blur.object = obj
    if enemyDist > 1.2:
        own['speed'] += own['accel']
        cont.activate(message)
    else:
        own['speed'] *= own['fric']
        cont.deactivate(message) 

    speed()
def speed():
    if own['speed'] > own['maxspd']:
        own['speed'] = own['maxspd']

    own.setLinearVelocity([0,own['speed'],0], True)
main()
```

Comment: You're going to have to include more relevant code. Possibly the *actual* traceback for the error message?

Comment: This could be any of several possible errors. We can't tell from the shown code fragment.

Comment: Are you sure it's `obj`, not `own`, that the compiler is complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if 'enemy' in obj:
    own['attack'] = obj
```

and set `own['attack'] = None` when no enemy is under attack.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this code:

```
def main():
    if click.positive:
        global obj
        obj = mouse.hitObject
        if 'enemy' in obj:
            own['attack'] = obj
        if 'enemy' not in obj:
            own['attack'] = obj
    if own['attack'] == obj:
         attack()
    if own['attack'] == None:
         free()
```

You will be comparing `own['attack']` to `obj` every time through the loop.
The first time through the loop, `obj` will not be defined and will throw the error.  One simple change would be to declare `global obj` outside of the mouseclick like this:

```
def main():
    global obj
    if click.positive:
        obj = mouse.hitObject
        if 'enemy' in obj:
            own['attack'] = obj
        if 'enemy' not in obj:
            own['attack'] = obj
    if own['attack'] == obj:
         attack()
    if own['attack'] == None:
         free()
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj` isn't set at the global scope. I see `cont`, `own`, `scene`, `flagEmpty`, `flag`, `enemy`, `mouse`, `click`, `track`, `message`, `blur`, `hit`, `distance`, and `enemyDistance`, but not `obj`.  I tried your code and warnings disappeared when I just put

```
obj = None
```

somewhere before `if 'init' not in own:`.

-Q